# Updating only some of object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a table in my database that I would like to be able to change some of the sections and keep the other functions as they were however it is updating the table so that the two are changed but the other 3 become empty. is there any way to change this?

```
 $(function Tuesday(){

 // CREATE A REFERENCE TO FIREBASE
 var dateTuesdayRef = new Firebase('https://shiftsapp.firebaseio.com/roster');

 // REGISTER DOM ELEMENTS
 var date2Field = $('#date2Input');
 var emp1put2Field = $('#emp1Input2');
 var emp2put2Field = $('#emp2Input2');
 var emp3put2Field = $('#emp3Input2');
 var emp4put2Field = $('#emp4Input2');
 var emp5put2Field = $('#emp5Input2');
 var enter2Field = $('#enter2');

 // LISTEN FOR KEYPRESS EVENT
 enter2Field.keypress(function (e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
     //FIELD VALUES
     var dateTuesday = date2Field.val();
     var emp1put2 = emp1put2Field.val();
  var emp2put2 = emp2put2Field.val();
  var emp3put2 = emp3put2Field.val();
  var emp4put2 = emp4put2Field.val();
  var emp5put2 = emp5put2Field.val();
  var enter2 = enter2Field.val();

  //SAVE DATA TO FIREBASE AND EMPTY FIELD
    var obj2 = {};
    obj2[dateTuesday] = {
    emp1:emp1put2, 
    emp2:emp2put2,
    emp3:emp3put2, 
    emp4:emp4put2, 
    emp5:emp5put2
    }

    dateTuesdayRef.child(dateTuesday).set({emp1:emp1put2, 
    emp2:emp2put2, 
    emp3:emp3put2, 
    emp4:emp4put2, 
    emp5:emp5put2});
    enter2Field.val('');
    }
});

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the values for the things you want to stay the same from your server, and feed them back when you set the object. You could also use a custom function to autofill undefined values like I have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

From the table at the top of the [Firebase guide on saving data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html):

> `set( )`:     Write or replace data to a defined path, like messages/users/
>
> `update( )`:  Update some of the keys for a defined path without replacing all of the data

So if you call `update()` instead of replace, it will only change the values of the properties you pass in and leave other values unmodified.